# Django ModelForms is ignoring a clean field method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model where I have a DateField:

```
class E(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255
    description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Start Date')
```

the ModelForm:

```
class EventModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['name', 'description','start_date']


    def clean_start_date(self):

       datetime_format = '%a %b %d %Y'
       start_date = self.cleaned_data['start_date']
       return datetime.strptime(start_date, datetime_format)
```

My issue is that Django ignores the clean method for the start_date, but take in consideration the clean methods for the other fields.

So I use the debugger to check, and I see that is appearing in `change_data`, but not in `cleaned_data`

```
changed_data: <class 'list'>: [name', 'description', ''start_date']
cleaned_data: name, description
```

which is strange, so I checked the input, and looks ok:

```
<input name="start_date" class="c-fi' type="text">
```

I don't understand why is not calling the clean method, instead make a validation on the Model a fails, so this is why I need clean to change date format before saving.

Comment: are you missing a comma(',') after 'description''start_date' in your fields section?? or its just a typo here?

Comment: thanks, is just and editing error, not related to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the date formats for the `DateField`, you should set [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateField.input_formats) instead.

```
class EventModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(
        verbose_name='Start Date',
        input_formats=['%a %b %d %Y'],
    )

class Meta:
    model = Event
    fields = ['name', 'description','start_date']
```

Since you are not including your custom format in the field, the field itself will raise a validation error, therefore the `clean_start_date` method never runs. You can read more about the order of validation [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation). Note that you shouldn't have to run `strptime` in a `clean_*` method for a `DateField` - the value in `cleaned_data` will already be a date by that point.

Comment: Oops, that should be on the form not the model. I've updated the answer.